# How can I make a custom validator fire even if a textbox is empty?

Tags: asp.net, validation, custom-validators

I set a custom validator on a textbox.

It only validates if there is some text in the textbox, I need it to fire all the time when someone clicks on the submit button.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

Set your [`CustomValidator.ValidateEmptyText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext.aspx) to `true`.

From MSDN:

> [ValidateEmptyText] [g]ets or sets a Boolean value indicating whether empty text should be validated.